# Add customer IP address to PayFlow Pro API request

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-payflow-pro

We're trying to add the IPAddressVelocity filter to our PayFlow Pro account, for fraud detection. In order for this filter to work we need to add CUSTIP to our payment API requests. CUSTIP is to pass along the user's IP address.

We can retrieve the customer's IP, no problem, but how can I add CUSTIP, as a part of my request object?

My suspicion is that this will require overloading Mage core files, but I want to be sure that I'm not missing something. And if that overloading is required, how should I add the new value to the request object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on my own. Created a module to overwrite Mage_Paypal_Model_Payflowpro that overrides _buildPlaceRequest and added the lines:

```
        $custIp = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
        if(!empty($custIp)){
            $request->setData('CUSTIP',$custIp);
        }
```

And she worked!!